# Shifting the +- voltage signs in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, circuitikz

Is there any way to shift the + and - signs so they are a little bit further apart?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, D*, v^=$v_g$] (2,0)
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|default|};
    \draw (0,1) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, D*, v^=$v_g$,label/align=rotate] (2,1)
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|label/align=rotate|};
    \draw (0,2) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, D*, v^=$\quad v_g$] (2,2) 
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|\quad|};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved another one myself by looking at source code...

It's `/tikz/circuitikz/voltage/distance from node`
(grrr, I wish these were documented)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    \draw (0,0) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, D*, v^=$v_g$] (2,0)
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|default|};
    \draw (0,1) to[/tikz/circuitikz/bipoles/length=0.6cm, 
             /tikz/circuitikz/voltage/distance from node=0.2cm,
             D*, v^=$v_g$] (2,1)
        node [right] {\tiny\verb|/tikz/circuitikz/voltage distance from node|};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: look also at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/560803/38080