# How can you change distance of +/- voltage signs in circuitikz from a component?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, circuitikz

In [Shifting the +- voltage signs in circuitikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/304528/shifting-the-voltage-signs-in-circuitikz) answer, they used "/tikz/circuitikz/voltage/distance from node" to set the distance that the +/- signs are away from the component (or well, node), and when I use that exact code, it works as shown, but I can't figure out why my code it doesn't seem to work.  Am I using ctikzset incorrectly?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, american, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{/tikz/circuitikz/voltage/distance from node=0.3cm}
\draw
    (0,0) to [generic, v<=40<\volt>] (0,3);
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{/tikz/circuitikz/voltage/distance from node=1cm}
\draw
    (0,0) to [generic, v<=40<\volt>] (0,3);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image: Different distance from node, but same figure]

Comment: Use `\ctikzset{bipoles/generic/voltage/distance from node=0.3cm}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I add the MWE with the suggestion of the very nice user @ferahfeza.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{bipoles/generic/voltage/distance from node=0.6cm}
\draw
    (0,0) to [generic, v<=40<\volt>] (0,3);
\end{circuitikz}

\begin{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{/tikz/circuitikz/voltage/distance from node=1cm}
\draw
    (0,0) to [generic, v<=40<\volt>] (0,3);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I will add an answer here because although the given answer works, it seems to me that it has a couple of misunderstandings.

First of all --- `\ctikzset{key}` is equivalent to (roughly) `\tikzset{/tikz/circuitikz/key}`, so the usage of that command is somehow redundant above.

Look at the following example:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[EFvoltages, siunitx, american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\draw (-2,0) to [generic, v<=1<\volt>, d-d] ++(0,3);
\ctikzset{voltage/distance from node=1cm}
\draw (0,0) to [generic, v<=2<\volt>, d-d] ++(0,3);
\ctikzset{bipoles/generic/voltage/distance from node=.3cm}
\draw (2,0) to [generic, v<=3<\volt>, d-d] ++(0,3);
\ctikzset{bipoles/generic/voltage/distance from node=1cm}
\draw (4,0) to [generic, v<=4<\volt>, d-d] ++(0,3);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The output it the following:

[image]

As you can see, it seems that the first `\ctikzset` is doing nothing --- the components with  1V and 2V have the same position of `+` and `-` (in reality, it is wreaking havoc, read on). This is because the `voltage/distance from node` key is the default one, which in the case of `generic` is overridden by the component-specific distance[*] `bipoles/generic/voltage/distance from node` which is set to `0.4`. The meaning is explained here --- this is a proportional distance from the node to the component:

[image]

...as you can see, now the command works as expected. Notice that if you use absolute values for the `distance from node` you are on yourself if the lead is smaller...

Technical note: the argument of `distance from node` is really used in a TikZ `calc` expression like: `($(node)!argument!(start of the component)$)`

Why is wreaking havoc the first command: because now it has set the distance to 1cm for *all* the components *minus* the special ones below...

There will be a documentation patch soon: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/438

---

- this happens for `generic`, `ageneric`, `memristor`, `fullgeneric` and `open`. I'll document it in the next version of the manual.

Comment: Excellent explanation.

Comment: Thank you for this, it helped solved my problem but when I read it the first (few) times I was trying to find out what the difference between the two pictures is (but there is no difference). Perhaps it would be helpful to say that the second picture is acutally the same as the first, but with additional markings.